# Restoring MULTIPLE MySQL databases from one file at the command line?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have exported all my databases to a file using phpMyAdmin.

Unfortunately I don't have a working phpMyAdmin in my destination system.

How should I restore all of them at once using one line command?

Comment: Did you take a look into the file? It should/could contain commands to create and switch to the databases as needed.

Comment: Yes, databases are created and then they have been selected using `USE database_name` command.

Comment: Then Unni and laurents answers are correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why don't you concat all the files into one single file and import/restore using

```
mysql -u username -p < dump.sql
```

Create one file using

```
mysqldump -u username -p --all-databases > dump.sql
```

Comment: The OP already has a single file and he needs to restore the files so he can't dump them anymore I suppose.

Comment: @laurent Yes got it. Using `mysql -u username -p < dump.sql` will load the multiple mysql database.

Comment: yes, sure it will

Comment: it did not work for me. it says i need to select a databse

Answer (score 3):

If you backed up many database to 1 file, I suppose you backed up the `create database` statements in the same file. If not you only need to add the `create database` and `use database` statements to your file at the proper places.

After that, the command to load the file to mysql is:

`mysql -p < sqlfile.sql`

`-p` is to ask for your password.

You can use `-u username` if you need to use another user.

Answer (score 1):

mysql command to restore sql file is :

```
mysql DATABASE_NAME < SQL_FILENAME.sql
```

first make sure that file is sql. Incase it ends with gz file extension, you need to uncompress using command :

```
gunzip SQL_FILE.sql.gz
```

Comment: -1 . As I said in the above, there are MULTIPLE databases stored in the file and I want all of them to be restored at once.

Comment: can you export each database separately in phpmyadmin and restore it at source server ? or use linux stream editors such as sed or awk to split them in different file.

Comment: no need, he can import all the databases from a single file

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax:

```
mysql  --user='root' --password='mypwd' db_name < /backuploaction.sql;
```